# Nullables and Not .HasValue vs. IsNothing Nothing

Tags: .net, vb.net, nullable

I've run into an 'interesting' conundrum with some code I wrote, and I can't find an adequate explanation for why an apparent 'fix' actually works where the original code didn't.

I've got a list of objects with associated calculations that build upon one another, and to avoid an exponential decrease in performance, I started caching a few key values (stored in Nullable) that look back at previous items in the list.  To clear the cached values, I set them to Nothing, and have some logic to check for that in order to recalculate them *once* when and update requires it.

The variable declaration:

```
Dim _nullable As System.Decimal? = Nothing
```

The original code:

```
If (Not Me._nullable.HasValue OrElse Me.OtherCondition) Then
```

The 'fixed' code:

```
If (Me._nullable Is Nothing OrElse Not Me._nullable.HasValue OrElse Me.OtherCondition) Then
```

Everything I understand about .NET's Nullables indicates that those two conditions should be functionally and logically identical, but changing the former to the latter fixed a bug.

Is there some functional difference between the two conditions that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: I'd expect those to be equivalent.  Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger to see if you can identify the difference in behavior?  You might need to go down to the disassembly level to see a difference.

Comment: Yes, I stepped through the debugger.  Unfortunately, it didn't clear anything up.

Comment: Can you show any more code? like what struct or type _nullable is, how it gets set if it does, and what sets it. I am guessing there is some type of boxing happening.

Comment: _nullable is defined as System.Decimal? (aka: System.Nullable<System.Decimal>).  It's on an object in a List<> collection, and there's a method that sets '_nullable' to Nothing which is called from that collection to clear the cached value in the edited object and all subsequent objects in the list.  None of that has changed.

Comment: What is the 'bug' then? Is _nullable is no longer Nothing and has a value of say 0?

Comment: Your code works as expected for me: [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uGk8tc) Pasting it into SharpLab shows that `Not _nullable.HasValue` and `_nullable Is Nothing` compile to exactly the same IL.

Comment: @tval That's the confusion.  By everything I understand, the two conditions should be logically equivalent, but it wasn't triggering before, and is triggering now.  It doesn't make any sense.  _nullable was set to Nothing by the exact same code either way.  My initial thought was that I'd stuffed up the boolean logic, and 'Not x OrElse y' was actually equivalent to 'Not (x OrElse y)', but that's not the case, so there's no reason I can find that adding the Is Nothing check should have altered the result at all.  The bug was that the row update wasn't triggering even though _nullable = Nothing.

Comment: @RichardDeeming That's what I'd expect based on what I understand about Nullables.  I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't seem to have been behaving the same.  It's literally the only code change I made, and the change was made as a shot in the dark, not because I expected it to actually do anything different.  It's perplexing.

Comment: Hmmm. Without seeing more code, it is difficult to reproduce your bug. The only possible bug I could foresee is if a method is returning Decimal instead of Decimal?

Comment: I tried storing both null and non-null `Decimal?` instances in both a `List(Of Decimal?)` and a `List(Of Object)`.  I tested `HasValue` (which required a cast on the output of the object container since I run with `Option Strict On`) and `Is Nothing` and got consistent results throughout.

Comment: Suddenly, it isn't working again, with literally no changes to the code since I posted the question.  I called the user over to verify that the results were correct in the updated grid, and it stopped updating the following rows again...  But as soon as I set breakpoints, and step through to watch the calculations, it works...  WTF?!

Comment: Is there threading involved?  That looks suspiciously like a race condition.

Comment: There's an ancient version of a third-party library (CSLA v1.8) involved.  That may be the issue.  I've literally toggled the breakpoints on/off during the same execution of the application, without so much as closing the form in question, and it works if breakpoints are set, and fails if they aren't.

Comment: The process is essentially: 1) read the values from the text boxes and convert them to the proper type; 2) Clear the cache of calculated values for the object associated with that row and all later rows; 3) Update the values in the object with the new values; 4) Re-bind the grid.  It's step #3 that triggers some 'black box' action from CSLA, so the cache should already be cleared, requiring that the values be recalculated for step #4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has become apparent with more investigation, the answer to my original question is that the two are, indeed identical to one another, and the cause of my issue is that I appear to have been unknowingly chasing a race condition of some sort.

Thanks for the assistance, everyone.